# DisableProfiler error on XGBoost fit

Tags: training, sagemaker

Suddenly, code that was working (before the Christmas break) now does not. I would like to know why. The documentation seems incomplete and the error message is cryptic in context.

On trying to fit a sagemaker estimator, I get an error

```
Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in ProfilerConfig: "S3OutputPath"
Unknown parameter in ProfilerConfig: "DisableProfiler", must be one of: S3OutputPath, ProfilingIntervalInMilliseconds, ProfilingParameters
```

The only thing that happened between was that one of the cloud engineers changed settings to allow a github repository to be copied locally (I was previously uploading a zip file). After that, it stopped working.
The specific code involved is as follows.

```
xgb_estimator = Estimator(
       container,
       role,
       instance_count=1,
       instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
       disable_profiler=True,
       sagemaker_session=session,
   )
   

   

xgb_estimator.set_hyperparameters(
       max_depth=5,
       eta=0.2,
       gamma=4,
       min_child_weight=6,
       subsample=0.8,
       disable_profiler=True,
       output_path = folder,
       num_round=800,
   )




 xgb_estimator.fit({"train": train_input, },  logs=False,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from Amazon - it worked.

It involves details that I did not know to include in the question originally.

I executed the code from a terminal created in Studio. It turns out that the provisioning for this can be volatile. I originally did get the provisioning to work but something in the background happened (details were not determined, but the stability problem of executing this way was emphasised by Amazon) and I was advised to create a notebook instance from the file menu and then there is an icon on the top line of the notebook for creating a terminal - which gets a root shell directly on a docker container that has access to the same (virtual) disk drive.

Upshot - running from a docker container created from a notebook instances created from the Studio file menu is much more stable.